Azure Analysis Service Tabular Cube - How To Impersonate A User in SSMS
Test Cube, Test User, connect to it(Azure Analysis Service) in SSMS, right click the cube, browse, click on "Impersonate":

And you will see a series of prompts that are specific to a on-premise implementation of AD, so local users, local groups(In this case it's just my local system):

How do I select a user from MS Entra through these prompts? If that can't been done is there another easy UI driven way to impersonate a user? Did Microsoft just not extend support for this authentication type to SSMS(at least for Azure Analysis Services)?

You can impersonate in the same window, but you should not go to select user and group window. When there is a selection for "other user" there, you just enter email and select ok. Then it can recognize the user if the user is already present in Azure AD. If the user selected as domainname/username format, then it can not register and hence it is not able to impersonate.
